# Is it possible to write an ANTLR grammar which allows a separator character to appear in an identifier?

Tags: antlr, grammar, lexer

Is it possible to write an ANTLR grammar such that:

`foo:bar:baz`

would be tokenized as `foo`, `:`, `bar:baz`?

The actual use case here is that we have a construct where we reference an object using the form `<TYPE>:<IDENTIFIER>` - where in other contexts `IDENTIFIER` is just a plain string, so can accommodate the `:` embedded in it. In this context, we're trying to perform a more complex parsing on an expression.

Comment: What happened to the first ':'??

Comment: Sure: `FOO: 'foo'; COLON: ':' -> skip; BARBAZ: 'bar:baz';`. But somehow I don't think that fits what you actually want. It would help if you specified *why* the `foo` in your example is its own token while `bar:baz` make up a single token together.

Comment: I've clarified the requirement.

Comment: So to be clear, the fact that you want `foo` to be its own token depends entirely on the parsing context and in a different context, you might want the whole thing to be tokenized as `foo:bar:baz`? If so, that's probably impossible (unless the "context switch" can be detected lexically (e.g. the instances where you want the identifier to stop at the next colon are always preceded by a certain keyword), in which case you might be able to do something with lexer modes). Probably your best bet would be to not include colons in identifiers and instead have a parser rule that matches `ID (':' ID)*`

Comment: This can be done, the easiest being with lexer modes. Otherwise, you'd need to write action code to test the input char stream and do wonderful Antlr char and token stream magic. `lexer grammar FooLexer; Type : [a-z]+ -> pushMode(DoIdentifier); mode DoIdentifier; Colon: ':'; Identifier: [a-z]+ ':' [a-z]+ -> popMode;`. If you have something other than TYPE for `[a-z]+`, then you'd need to add another lexer mode. The modes should have a fallback rule to set the mode.

Comment: kaby76's suggestion might work for you, but that will not work if your grammar allows for "single" identifiers being present (a single `foo`, without a colon). There is more information needed about the language to give a decent answer, IMO.